# PHP Dev Tools on Eclipse 3.8 Ubuntu - conflicting dependencies

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, eclipse-pdt, mylyn

I am trying to install PHP Development Tools in Eclipse 3.8 on Ubuntu. I have had several failed dependencies and I have managed to track them down and install them, notably as regards mylyn. Then when I installed org.eclipse.mylyn.context_feature.feature.group I get errors that are too complex for me to figure out.

Repository: http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna

Package: PDT 3.4.0.201....

Here is what Eclipse tells me:

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: PHP Development Tools (PDT) 3.4.0.201502171754 (org.eclipse.php.feature.group 3.4.0.201502171754)
  Software currently installed: Eclipse Platform 3.7.0.debbuild (org.eclipse.platform.ide 3.7.0.debbuild)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Bidirectional Text Support 0.10.0.v20130327-1442 (org.eclipse.equinox.bidi 0.10.0.v20130327-1442)
    Bidirectional Text Support 0.9.0.dist (org.eclipse.equinox.bidi 0.9.0.dist)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: PHP Development Tools (PDT) 3.4.0.201502171754 (org.eclipse.php.feature.group 3.4.0.201502171754)
    To: org.eclipse.php.ui [3.4.0.201502171754]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: PDT UI Plug-in 3.4.0.201502171754 (org.eclipse.php.ui 3.4.0.201502171754)
    To: bundle org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.ui 0.0.0
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse Platform 3.8.1.dist-A8F8_IVRG4VZSCmeloKVfCrtIFotGyJZcMPL9 (org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 3.8.1.dist-A8F8_IVRG4VZSCmeloKVfCrtIFotGyJZcMPL9)
    To: org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group [3.8.1.dist-8LA2GODFTJUDJ21934]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse Platform 3.7.0.debbuild (org.eclipse.platform.ide 3.7.0.debbuild)
    To: org.eclipse.platform.feature.group [3.8.1.dist-A8F8_IVRG4VZSCmeloKVfCrtIFotGyJZcMPL9]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse RCP 3.8.1.dist-8LA2GODFTJUDJ21934 (org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group 3.8.1.dist-8LA2GODFTJUDJ21934)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.bidi [0.9.0.dist]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: WTP UI Plug-in 1.2.300.v201401292051 (org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.ui 1.2.300.v201401292051)
    To: bundle org.eclipse.equinox.bidi [0.10.0,2.0.0)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: WTP UI Plug-in 1.2.300.v201401292115 (org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.ui 1.2.300.v201401292115)
    To: bundle org.eclipse.equinox.bidi [0.10.0,2.0.0)
```

Any and all help appreciated.

Comment: Well you appear to be trying to install code designed for Eclipse 4.4 (Luna) on Eclipse 3.8 - far to old.

Comment: OK thanks for this, greg-449. To be fair it does not help that Eclipse gives Really Useful Identities like "Juno" or "Luna" that give us no clue as to how old the code is, or that 3.8 does not seem to have a name (none in splash screen, about window) but I digress. Would anyone happen to know what repository to use?

Comment: The Wikipedia page for [Eclipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29#Name) gives the names. Eclipse 3.8 and 4.2 are both Eclipse Juno (this was a transition release from the 3.x to 4.x releases).

Comment: OK thanks. I will work with Juno for now.

Answer (score 0):

If you want install eclipse pdt 3.4 on older eclipse releases you should use direct sites instead of simulates release update site:

1. PDT: http://download.eclipse.org/tools/pdt/updates/3.4 or http://download.eclipse.org/tools/pdt/updates/latest
2. DLTK 5.1.1: http://download.eclipse.org/technology/dltk/updates-dev/5.1.1/

After that you'll be able to install PDT 3.4 on eclipse 3.8

Comment: Thank you both greg-449 and zulus. I finally just removed Juno and installed Luna and PHP is right there be default, works like a charm. Thanks for the pointers.

Answer (score 0):

In the end the problem stemmed from trying to install a lot of stuff on an old version of Eclipse. This in turn stemmed from apt-get repositories that were not up-to-date. So when I tried to update my Eclipse I was told it was the latest version and I believed it, until greg-449 straightened me out.

Since I could not use apt-get or Ubuntu software centre (same thing) to install the latest Eclipse I just removed the installation and downloaded and unzipped Luna in a directory somewhere. I recommend this course of action if you are using Eclipse on Ubuntu.